# DevExpress WPF grid: can ShowCheckBoxSelectorColumn be fixed (i.e. added to FixedLeftVisibleColumns)?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-wpf

DevExpress grid allows to automatically create a special column that shows checkboxes. They behave as selectors for the grid's rows. It is achieved by enabling `TableView`'s `ShowCheckBoxSelectorColumn` property.

Is there some way to fix this column to the left so that it is always visible when you scroll horizaontally? It is not in the `.Grid.Columns` collection, obviously, so is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be impossible to do.

This special "selector" column exists in the view's `VisibleColumns`, but not in `.Grid.Columns`. It is possible to get it from `VisibleColumns` on some event and set `column.Fixed = FixedStyle.Left;`. This operation eventually calls `DataViewBehavior.RebuildVisibleColumnsCore`, which enumerates `.Grid.Columns` that does not have the selector column, so the Fixed style is not eventually taken into account.

Probably one should pin the first of the data columns, as this also pins the selector column.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible devexpress has a solution posted -> https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T578471/fix-checkboxselectorcolumn-on-left-side

Add a static constructor to the main window with the following code to fix the selector column to the left side.

```
     static MainWindow()
    {
        BaseColumn.FixedProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GridColumn), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, value) => ((GridColumn)d).FieldName == TableView.CheckBoxSelectorColumnName ? FixedStyle.Left : value));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the column object name and set the FixedStyle property to left.
Example: colUsername.FixedStyle = FixedStyle.Left;